# Why do we need the `match` in many functions

Tags: r

I'm struggling with understanding the usage of `match` in many functions in R. For example,

```
function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
contrasts = NULL, offset, ...) 
{
  cl <- match.call()
  mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", 
      "offset"), names(mf), 0L)
  mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]

  mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
  mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
  mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
  ...
```

Why do we need `match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", "offset"), names(mf), 0L)` in this case? What does it do?

Comment: Are you asking what match does in this case? I’m not sure there’s another answer to ‘why do so many packages use it?’ Other than ‘because they need to match elements of vectors’.

Comment: @user438383 what does it mean by "match elements of vectors"? I'm sorry but I'm really new to R so with all due respect, you can keep all the ridicule to yourself. It produces several 0s, if I run in my R.

Comment: I’m not ridiculing you, I’m asking for clarification because I didn’t understand the scope of your question. To learn what the function does type ?match in the terminal.

Comment: @user438383 then why does it return 6 zeros in this case? I'm really confused. I also have no idea what mf[c(1L, m)] does.

Comment: `?match` says "match returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second.", in your case there is no match. The doc for the `nomatch` arg is "the value to be returned in the case when no match is found. Note that it is coerced to integer.". Here it is set to 0, so you get a vector of 0s

Comment: `mf[c(1L, m)]` subsets a call using the 1st element, which is the function names, and the the above matches, which are the position of arguments named "formula" etc. This is basically creating a call restricted to 6 arguments

Answer (score 2):

First, I will rewrite the modeling function so as to save the intermediate steps in the creation of the argument to `eval`.
The object `mf` starts as one of the possible outputs of `match.call` and is altered 3 times.
These steps are saved in `mf1`, `mf2` and `mf3` and returned to caller.

```
modeling_function <-
  function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = "qr", 
            model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, 
            contrasts = NULL, offset, ...) 
  {

    cl <- match.call()
    mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)

    # save the current value of 'mf' (1st time)
    mf1 <- mf
    
    m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", 
                 "offset"), names(mf), 0L)
    mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
    
    # save the current value of 'mf' (2nd time)
    mf2 <- mf
    
    mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
    mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)

    # save the current value of 'mf' (3rd time)
    mf3 <- mf
    
    mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
    list(
      call_without_dots = cl,
      call_with_dots = mf1,
      names_with_dots = names(mf1),
      m = m,
      after_match_argv = mf2,
      before_eval = mf3,
      after_eval = mf
    )
  }
```

Now the first call to `modeling_function`, without any extra argument passed on in the dots argument.

```
mod <- modeling_function(Species ~ ., data = head(iris), na.action = na.omit)
```

`match.call()` returns an object of class `"call"`, in the first case without expanding the dots argument, if present.
It's easier to see what information it holds coercing it to list.

1. the function name;
2. each of the arguments passed to the function.

The first argument is not named, the others have the function's arguments names.

```
as.list(mod$call_without_dots)
# [[1]]
# modeling_function
# 
# $formula
# Species ~ .
# 
# $data
# head(iris)
#
# $na.action
# na.omit
```

There were no extra arguments so this list is exactly the same as the list above.

```
as.list(mod$call_with_dots)  # output omited
```

Then the code determines which of the arguments is an argument to `stats::model.frame`.
This is done by matching the vector

```
c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", "offset")
```

to the names of the arguments actually passed to the function and now in `mf`.

1. the first two arguments, `"formula"` and `"data"` are numbers 2 and 3 in the call list;
2. then `"subset"` and `"weights"` were not used in the call and there are two 0´s;
3. `"na.action"` is number 4 in the call list;
4. finally, `"offset"` is also not present and corresponds to a end 0.

The output of `match` is of length 6, the length of the matched vector.

```
mod$names_with_dots
# [1] ""          "formula"   "data"      "na.action"
mod$m
# [1] 2 3 0 0 4 0
```

`mf` is updated to include the 1st member (the function name) and the arguments the user actually needs:

```
mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
```

But there is one `model.frame` argument the function programmers or maintainers have decide should be set by the function.
If any of the response or regressors is a factor, then the unused factor levels should always be dropped.
`model.frame` defaults to keeping unused factor levels and after analyzing the problem this function solves, the programmers want this behavior to change, not letting the user decide on this. That is why `drop.unused.levels` is not a function argument. Prior to this all the work was about what the function users can pass to the function, now a hard-coded function behavior is going to be set for `model.frame` to process.

Therefore, the call object `mf` gets a new member, `drop.unused.levels = TRUE`.

It is important to note that up until now the formula has not been evaluated in the frame or environment of the `data` argument. So far the data is a [promise](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects).

This is the call object for `eval` to evaluate. It will call `model.frame` passing it 4 arguments.

```
as.list(mod$before_eval)
# [[1]]
# stats::model.frame
# 
# $formula
# Species ~ .
# 
# $data
# head(iris)
# 
# $na.action
# na.omit
# 
# $drop.unused.levels
# [1] TRUE
```

The output of `model.frame` is a complicated object, they usually are. The data itself - evaluated - and several attributes set.

```
as.list(mod$after_eval)
#  $Species
#  [1] setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa setosa
#  Levels: setosa
#  
#  $Sepal.Length
#  [1] 5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5.0 5.4
#  
#  $Sepal.Width
#  [1] 3.5 3.0 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
#  
#  $Petal.Length
#  [1] 1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
#  
#  $Petal.Width
#  [1] 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4
#  
#  attr(,"terms")
#  Species ~ Sepal.Length + Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width
#  attr(,"variables")
#  list(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
#  attr(,"factors")
#               Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
#  Species                 0           0            0           0
#  Sepal.Length            1           0            0           0
#  Sepal.Width             0           1            0           0
#  Petal.Length            0           0            1           0
#  Petal.Width             0           0            0           1
#  attr(,"term.labels")
#  [1] "Sepal.Length" "Sepal.Width"  "Petal.Length" "Petal.Width" 
#  attr(,"order")
#  [1] 1 1 1 1
#  attr(,"intercept")
#  [1] 1
#  attr(,"response")
#  [1] 1
#  attr(,".Environment")
#  <environment: R_GlobalEnv>
#  attr(,"predvars")
#  list(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, Petal.Width)
#  attr(,"dataClasses")
#       Species Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
#      "factor"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"    "numeric"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

---

Slightly off-topic, here is the initial call objects when extra arguments are passed on as the dots argument value.

```r
mod <- modeling_function(Species ~ ., data = head(iris), na.action = na.omit,
                         other_arg = "other arg", that = 1:3)

as.list(mod$call_without_dots)
#  [[1]]
#  modeling_function
#  
#  $formula
#  Species ~ .
#  
#  $data
#  head(iris)
#  
#  $na.action
#  na.omit
#  
#  $other_arg
#  [1] "other arg"
#  
#  $that
#  1:3
as.list(mod$call_with_dots)
#  [[1]]
#  modeling_function
#  
#  $formula
#  Species ~ .
#  
#  $data
#  head(iris)
#  
#  $na.action
#  na.omit
#  
#  $...
#  $...$other_arg
#  [1] "other arg"
#  
#  $...$that
#  1:3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks again. This answer helped me a lot to understand.